# Optimalization of a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I need some advices or tips for optimize this loop.
My code has three loops looking like below one:

```
Worksheets("Prod.Lines").PivotTables("QTY").PivotFields("Production group").EnableMultiplePageItems = True
        With Worksheets("Prod.Lines").PivotTables("QTY").PivotFields("Production group")
            For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count - 1
            .PivotItems(.PivotItems(i).Name).Visible = False
            Next i
             .PivotItems("A").Visible = True
             .PivotItems("B").Visible = True
             .PivotItems("BA").Visible = True
        End With
```

Edit: Problem is with "unchecking" 60 pivot items in this pivot table. Its taking a lot of time, and each loop is clearing these filters. So my macro must hide 180 items in total.

Tried to resolve my problem with array but I was unable to create a loop which will checking value of cell with defined arrays.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I don't see what the problem is in your code. Can you please clarify. *"Problem is with "unchecking" 60 pivot items in this pivot table."* is a pretty broad error description. Please [edit] and add some more details where your issue is.

Comment: Try setting the table's `ManualUpdate` property before changing the item visibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425291/pivot-table-manual-update-not-working